# require('module/component') when component.js is not in module root?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I'm trying to create a npm package of a couple React components. These will be used in a couple of other projects so I would like them in a separate package.

What I would like to be able to do is `require('comps/a-component')` from an app using this package. I could do this by putting all my components in the root of the module, but I don't want to do that. Instead I want to have all components in src/components/ because the root will be overcrowded.

This seems like a trivial thing to do but I have not yet succeeded. I've looked through https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json trying to find an option to set the root or something. Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make symlink in you node_modules directory to your components directory. This would allow you to require your components from anywhere in your app like you said: `require('comps/a-component')`. To create the symlink on a linux or osx you can do something like this

```
cd ./node_modules; ln -snf ../src/components comps;
```

Another option would be to actually create npm packages out of each component, that way you could have them listed in your dependencies of your package.json.

Another promising option that was released in npm 2.0 are local dependencies. This allows you to point to a local npm package on your file system. In this case each component would have to be written as an npm package with a package.json https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

Comment: Thanks, I will probably go with the symlink option. Creating a module out of each component is not really an option since "a couple components" in my case in probably more like 20+ :)

Answer (score 0):

If your app is like this:

```
- AppFolder
   |-index.js
   |-Readme.md
   |-/src
      |-app.js
      |-anotherThing.js
```

If I want to use `anotherThing.js`, I can just do `var anotherThing = require('./src/anotherThing');`. Unless I fail to understand your problem.

Or maybe you meant [the `main` attribute in `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main)

Comment: I could do `require('comps/src/components/a-component')`, but it feels a bit verbose.

Comment: use the `main` attribute then in `package.json`. I think that's what you need.

Comment: I tried using the main attribute, but that doesn't change the modules root/search path, It only points out the main module.

Comment: No, sorry for not being clear. Have one JS file that is your main entry point e.g: `index.js`. You require your folder in there (i.e `module.exports = require('src/someModule')`). And then you point to that file using `main` attribute for `package.json`. That way, if someone requires your module from npm, they get everything as you wanted.

Comment: Ah ok I see. Yes that might be an option, except that this will always include all components. If i only use one component I don't want to include all components. It's a library that will be used with browserify.